# PHP Html Email using Pear HTML Table and Pear Email

Tags: php, mime-types, pear, html-table, html-email

I am facing quite strange issue, I've php script which sends out an email to the list of users containing HTML table(with the data) and CSV attachment of the same data. The problem is when that script to send out more then 10 emails, in some of the emails we get

--=_f3be233a9b22e88524e1539166c49be0 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

in email body and HTML table lost the formatting as well, however CSV data is absolutely fine in that email.

Basically the purpose of the script is to pick the data according to user subscribe information(database-table) and send it to the subscribe user early morning. Every night the database tables are updated with the new data, which is picked up by that PHP script and send in an email. Further that PHP script trigger by Windows Schedule task.
Below is the code of the application.

```
if($ix>0)
{
    while(odbc_fetch_row($subRes2))
    {
            $s_email=odbc_result($subRes2, 1);
            //echo $s_email;





     $from = "Sender <alerts@xxx.com>";
     $to = "$s_email";
     $subject = "Information_DB:" . $arrayE . " Restored on: " . "-";


    $host = "xxxinternal.xxxx.com";
    $port = "25";
    //disabled the username and password because currently sending unauthenticated email.
   // $username = "";  //<> give errors
    //$password = "";
    //add the email headers 29082013 1008 - SMS
    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject,
    'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => false));
        //'username' => $username,
        //'password' => $password));

$subject = "Results from query";
$crlf = "\n";

   $mime_params = array(
       'text_encoding' => '7bit',
       'text_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
       'html_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
       'head_charset'  => 'UTF-8'
    );
    // Creating the Mime message
    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    // Setting the body of the email
    //$mime->setTXTBody($body);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
    $file='./wamp/www/' . $csv_filename;
    $mime->addAttachment($csv_filename,'application/octet-stream');

    $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    // Sending the email
   // $mail =& Mail::factory('mail');

     $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    //  echo "<script>window.close()</script>";
     } 
     else {
      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     }
     }}}

     else
     {
     $from = "Sender <alert@xxx.com>";
      $to = "$s_email";
      $subject = "Information_DB:" . $arrayE . " Restored on: " . "-";

  //$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
  $host = "xxxinternal.xxxx.com";
    $port = "25";
    //disabled the username and password because currently sending  unauthenticated email.
   // $username = "";  //<> give errors
    //$password = "";
    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject,
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');


?>
```

Unfortunately when we tested I could't seen this issue. But when its went UAT lots of user get this issue and it seems to be consistent with the database. For e.g. if user A is subscribe with Spain and Russian data, then consistently they experience the issue with Russian Data email (contains the mentioned headers in the email) however Spain data email is fine. In the live its probably sending around 100's of email daily.

I will appreciate if any of you please point me out what is going wrong as I am setting up the UTF-8 character set in an email mime setup but still getting this issue.

Regards
Shoaib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with mime type, which require to code again. Basically the message I was sending was not encoded with UTF-8 which I did. This time I user Mail_mimePart instead of Mail_mime and it works treat.

That example was very very helpful

---ahttp://tiger-fish.com/comment/reply/133---

and some of the parameter explanation for Mail_mimePart can be found on below link

ahttp://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mimepart.mail-mimepart.php---

How to attach the attachment using Mail_mimePart.

ahttp://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mimepart.addsubpart.php---

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are sending emails too fast that may occur in the result of `spam/unwantd` email use `sleep(4)` to create the `4 sec delay` in next `mail.

Comment: sleep doesnt work it stops the process after sending one email.